# What is the word for "now" in Classical Latin?

Tags: classical-latin

I found that the translation for the word "now" is "nunc."

Is it correct that in the Latin language that there only exists capital letters and that the letter "U" is "V"?

If so, would it be correct that the translation of the word now is:
NVNC?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple levels of accuracy to classical Latin writing. In order to least extreme to most extreme accuracy, there are:

1. The letters do not have macrons or symbols denoting their stress.
2. 'V' and 'I" are used instead of 'U' and 'J' (J is later used instead of 'I' when the sound is 'yuh' rather than 'ih.')
3. Everything is in capital letters, since classical Latin did not have an upper or lower case.
4. The script itself might slightly differ from the letter shapes in our alphabet. I don't know enough about that script though. For true accuracy in this area, I look to the other scholars on the Latin Language Stack Exchange.

So in answer to your question, NVNC is extremely faithful to classical Latin! It's the best you can do on a keyboard, anyway.

Comment: If you consider the [apex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apex_\(diacritic\)) to be a kind of macron (or vice versa), retaining it is perfectly historical for classical Latin.

Comment: I am sure that "capitol" letters were used on the other six hills as well.